# Inline insert image into text area Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Is any module helps to download image file and insert image link into any place  of text area by button,not by writting some link information in insert image dialog in CKEditor, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Media module for drupal.

> Enables the user of remote media from sites like YouTube, Flickr or any oEmbed provider.

https://www.drupal.org/project/media

Comment: I'll look at it. It could be useful.